# Lodash. Получить объект по свойству

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, lodash

Хочу получить объект из массива объектов по указанному свойству. Массив - это route map.
Все прекрасно, но если в конце свойства есть цифры, которые могут динамически меняться, то все ломается

```
const arr = [
  {url: '/team/:teamId([0-9]+)', name: 'Some name'},
  {url: '/home', name: 'Some name 12'}
];
```

Функция для получения

`getPageName = url => _.find(arr, ['url', url]).name`;

Может кто-то знает, как учесть динамически меняющиеся цифры?
Пример url'ов:
`/team/3`
`/team/120`

Затеял все это, чтоб получать название страницы при попадании на нее..

Home страницу получить не составляет труда, как вы уже поняли, а вот Team page - нет.

Comment: Покажите пример данных, в которых есть *динамически меняющиеся цифры*.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko я показал - /team/:teamId([0-9]+) - teamId может быть 2, а может быть 102

Comment: Нет, вы показали условие, по которому строится url. Но вы не показали сами url'ы.

Comment: хорошо, `/team/3`, `/team/89` - имеется в виду что-то такое

Comment: Добавьте эту информацию в вопрос, пожалуйста.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko добавил...

Answer (score 1):

Можно попробовать что-то вроде такого.

```js
const arr = [{
    url: '/team/:teamId([0-9]+)',
    name: 'Some name'
  },
  {
    url: '/team/:teamId([0-9]+)/:playerId([a-c]{3})',
    name: 'Some name'
  },
  {
    url: '/home',
    name: 'Some name 12'
  }
];

function getRoute(arr, url) {

  const getRegExp = (urlRoute) => {
    const regexp = /[:].+\((.*)\)/;
    const paths = urlRoute.split('/').map(m => {
      const res = regexp.exec(m);
      return res ? m.replace(res[0], res[1]) : m;
    });
    return paths.join('/') + '$';
  }

  return arr.find(el => {
    const regexp = getRegExp(el.url);
    if (regexp) {
      return (new RegExp(regexp)).test(url);
    } else {
      return el.url === url;
    }
  });
}
console.log(getRoute(arr, '/team/2'));
console.log(getRoute(arr, '/team/2/aaa'));
```

Comment: это не совсем то, входящий url должен быть вида `/team/4`, а не `'/team/teamId9'`

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn ага, тупанул маленько)

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn Обновил ответ)

Comment: сделал чуть иначе, спасибо вам

Comment: @VladyslavTereshyn интересно будет посмотреть ваше решение. Опубликуйте его как ответ, может кому-то в будущем он и поможет!